# Group by not return null values

Tags: mysql

So I have used GROUP BY like and it works :

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as count FROM hpg_outgoing_datas
WHERE YEAR(outgoing_data_date) = $param
GROUP BY MONTH(outgoing_data_date)
```

The result is:

```
1856
4076
4313
4590
3636
26412
6165
17694
25325
12321
10750
```

but i want get this result

```
0
1856
4076
4313
4590
3636
26412
6165
17694
25325
12321
10750
```

In the first month there is no data

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. And, for next time, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a query that returns all the months (1-12) and left join the table so you can count all the months even those that don't exist in the table:

```
SELECT m.month, COUNT(h.outgoing_data_date) as count 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
) m LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM hpg_outgoing_datas
  WHERE YEAR(outgoing_data_date) = $param
) h ON MONTH(h.outgoing_data_date) = m.month
GROUP BY m.month
```